# Some authentication problem while making bootable USB using rufus

Tags: windows, authentication, usb, bootable

In windows 10, I'm trying to install ubuntu with USB. For making bootable USB, I'm using rufus.
However, there occurs an authentication problem even though I logged in Windows with an administrator account.

Here's the log from rufus.

```
Will reuse 'ldlinux.sys' and 'ldlinux.bss' from './rufus_files/rufus_files/syslinux-6.03/20171017/' for Syslinux installation
Format operation started
Requesting disk access...
Opened \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1 for exclusive write access
Requesting lock...
ABORTED: Cannot use an image that is located on the target drive!
\\?\Volume{d0782feb-cabc-11e8-b19e-806e6f6e6963}\ was already mounted as D:\
Re-mounted volume as 'D:' after error
Found USB 2.0 device 'Generic Flash Disk USB Device' (058F:6387)
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 8 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 979, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x1F76D35D
Drive has an unknown Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: NTFS (0x07)
  Size: 7.5 GB (8048869376 bytes)
  Start Sector: 8192, Boot: No
Found USB 2.0 device 'Generic Flash Disk USB Device' (058F:6387)
1 device found
Disk type: Removable, Disk size: 8 GB, Sector size: 512 bytes
Cylinders: 979, Tracks per cylinder: 255, Sectors per track: 63
Partition type: MBR, NB Partitions: 1
Disk ID: 0x1F76D35D
Drive has an unknown Master Boot Record
Partition 1:
  Type: NTFS (0x07)
  Size: 7.5 GB (8048869376 bytes)
  Start Sector: 8192, Boot: No
```

It seems like there's some problem during locking.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `ABORTED: Cannot use an image that is located on the target drive!`

The line above means that you are trying to write the drive on which your ISO resides. This is the equivalent to sawing the branch you are sitting on!

Of course, Rufus cannot **erase** a drive if the image you want to apply resides on that drive.

Please remember that Rufus **always** repartitions and reformats a drive, so you cannot use anything from that drive, especially not an ISO.

The solution: Move your `.iso` file somewhere else that isn't the USB drive you are trying to use with Rufus.

Answer (score 1):

after formatting your USB and installing windows, you have one problem after formatting your USB!

USB can't detect in mp3 player, mobile phones, and car.

solve problem =>

1. open Rufus
2. choose "MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI" in the partition scheme.
3. unchoose "create a bootable disk usage"
4. unchoose "Create extended label and icon files"
5. click "START" for formatting your USB.